# How can I combine two similiar javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, performance

Is there a way to combine the following two instructions into more efficient code?

```
  $('.sandwiches').mouseleave(function () {
    $('.sandwiches').hide();
});
$('.food').mouseleave(function () {
    $('.sandwiches').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Merge the selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
$('.sandwiches, .food').mouseleave(function () {
    $('.sandwiches').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

By combining the selectors:

```
$('.sandwiches,.food').mouseleave...
```

Comment: I have no idea. If you're worried about that, you may want to use the newer method: `$('.sandwiches,.food').on('mouseleave',function...);` which I believe creates just one.

Comment: if it is about efficiency I guess this is important to reduce callback numbers

Comment: @Sebas, `.mouseleave` is identical to `.on('mouseleave')` in that they both bind the handler to every element in the matched selection. In the case of delegated events (i.e. `$('.foo').on('mouseleave', '.bar', fn)`) handlers are bound to every element in the *initial* matched selection (i.e. every `.foo` element would have a handler, but it's likely that the `.bar` elements are far more numerous).

Answer (score 0):

You could attach a defined function to each element:

```
function hideElement(e) {
    $(this).hide();
}

$('.sandwiches,.food').mouseleave(hideElement);
```